# Fastest way to concatenate list of audio files of different format?

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp3 -i b.wav -i c.mp3 -i d.aac -i e.mp3 -i f.mp3 -filter_complex concat=n=4:v=0:a=1[a] -map [a] -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 256k vout.mp3
```

This is the command I'm using currently to concatenate a list of audio files. Is there any faster way to merge songs using ffmpeg ?

Answer (score 2):

Try a different encoder. If you prefer MP3 try *shine*. From the [shine website](https://github.com/toots/shine):

> shine is a blazing fast mp3 encoding library implemented in
>   fixed-point arithmetic. The library can thus be used to performe super
>   fast mp3 encoding on architectures without a FPU, such as armel, etc..
>   It is also, however, also super fast on architectures with a FPU!

You can see some benchmarks on the same site.

You'll need to install shine, configure `ffmpeg` with `--enable-libshine`, and use it with `-c:a libshine`.

Quality per bitrate may not be as good as LAME, but mobile users won't care or notice.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no faster way.

Since you are concatenating files with different codecs and containers, you have to pass the audio through a `concat` filter, which requires re-encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm currently developing an android app with FFmpeg integrated. for concatenating 2 audio file my phone taking about 5 minutes with this command. But another app already in the play store doing the same in a minute with FFmpeg. So, I think I have to improve my coding side to improve encoding speed.